# Data binding with ng-option dropdown in Angular

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, drop-down-menu, ng-options

I have a dropdown and I want to display a value based on the dropdown selection in Angular. I am using ng-options and figure a simple data binding should work, but the data binding isn't showing up. Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IptAt3e5EZi15OObfWFr?p=preview

```
      <select ng-model="defcom"
        ng-options="opt.DefCom as opt.DefCom for opt in acct_info | filter:{Req:'MUST'}:true" >
      </select>
      <select ng-model="defcust"
        ng-options="opt.Customer as opt.Customer for opt in cust_info | filter: {Com: defcom}: true">
      </select>
      <p>{{ cust_info.Name }}</p>
```

in the controller:

```
$scope.cust_info = [
      {
        "Customer": "1",
        "Com": "1",
        "Name": "First Name"
      },
      {
        "Customer": "2",
        "Com": "1",
        "Name": "Second Name"
      },
      {
        "Customer": "3",
        "Com": "4",
        "Name": "Third Name"
      }];
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`{{cust_info.Name}}`

you are trying to reference `Name` incorrectly, you have an array of objects which each have `Name` therefore that will not work.

Change it to:

`{{cust_info[defcust - 1].Name}}`

-1 because "Customer" starts at 1 and not 0

and you will get the nth index inside `cust_info`, where the nth index was selected by the user and stored into `defcust`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/WHkijq8ea0ATnO4JXnc9?p=preview

Comment: The other user is right, if it is by index it needs a -1. What if I don't want to select by the index but rather the option chosen? Such as here: http://plnkr.co/edit/8rfBM4Lz8C1jSQCoPAmL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

{{cust_info[defcust-1].Name}} should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Without using the index to achieve this needs a little more javascript in there I guess.. I've added some. Hope this helps.. See this demo

```
<select ng-model="defcom" ng-change="change_acc(defcom)"
    ng-options="opt.DefCom as opt.DefCom for opt in acct_info | filter:{Req:'MUST'}:true" >
  </select>
  <select ng-model="defcust" ng-change="change_cust(defcust)"
    ng-options="opt.Customer as opt.Customer for opt in cust_info | filter: {Com: defcom}: true">
  </select>

http://plnkr.co/edit/pf6PtOWANfLxulQupqZq?p=preview
```

Comment: I managed to do it without using the index, but then I lost the default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583813/ng-options-default-value-for-angular-dropdown