# ng-options Default Value for Angular Dropdown

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, drop-down-menu, default, ng-options

I have two dropdowns, one is dependent on the other. I originally had my code using ng-repeat but read that it is more efficient to use ng-options. However, in switching over, I can't use ng-selected for the default any longer.

I've looked at different methods of setting the default option in ng-options but they use either `<option value="">Select Something Here</option>` for a customized option or selecting straight from the dataset. However my value will be changing.

Here is a plunker missing the default using ng-option:

http://plnkr.co/edit/VwqrsR38GOFubW8i46FJ?p=preview

I have the controller like so:

```
      <select ng-model="defcom"
        ng-options="opt as opt.DefCom for opt in acct_info | filter:{Req:'MUST'}:true" >
      </select>
       <p>Hello {{ defcom.AcctName }}</p>
```

and an example of my data:

```
$scope.acct_info = [
      {
        "Req": "MUST",
        "DefCom": "1",
        "AcctName": "ThisName"
      },
      {
        "Req": "NoMUST",
        "DefCom": "5",
        "AcctName": "ThisName2"
      },
      {
        "Req": "MUST",
        "DefCom": "4",
        "AcctName": "ThisName3"
      },
      {
        "Req": "MUST",
        "DefCom": "7",
        "AcctName": "ThisName4"
      }
    ];
```

I had it working when I used `ng-options="opt.DefCom as opt.DefCom for opt in acct_info | filter:{Req:'MUST'}:true"` as seen here: http://plnkr.co/edit/vyJuZDM7OvE5knsfHln7?p=preview
 but I changed it in order to get the associated bindings. If anyone has more insight to the way ng-options works that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-options="opt as opt.DefCom for opt in acct_info | filter:{Req:'MUST'}:true"`

The value bound to `ng-model="defcom"` will be an entire object `opt`. To set a default, you need to assign an entire object to `$scope.defcom` . e.g. `$scope.defCom = $scope.acct_info[2];`

With your current data, this will make the default

```
{
  "Req": "MUST",
  "DefCom": "4",
  "AcctName": "ThisName3"
}
```

Of course, you may not always know what your data will be so you may want to write some functions to get accounts or customers by one of their properties.

```
$scope.defcom = getAccountByDefCom("4");
$scope.defcust = getCustomer("3");

function getAccountByDefCom(defcom) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.acct_info.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.acct_info[i].DefCom === defcom) {
      return $scope.acct_info[i];
    }
  }
}

function getCustomer(number) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cust_info.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.cust_info[i].Customer === number) {
      return $scope.cust_info[i];
    }
  }
}
```

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e0Q7lr27fNBFvWmRSmVl?p=preview)

Having a look at the *Arguments* section of the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) may help